# Is the returned value of timeit.timeit the average or the best?

Tags: python, performance

the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) tells us clearly that timeit Command-Line Interface outputs the best.

```
python -m timeit '"-".join(map(str, range(100)))'
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.2 usec per loop
```

how about the Python Interface?

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('char in text', setup='text = "sample string"; char = "g"')
0.41440500499993504
```

is it still the best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line sets the `repeat` option to 3:

> ```
> -r N, --repeat=N
> ```
>
> how many times to repeat the timer (default 3)

and 'the best' is the best out of those 3. That's different from the *number* parameter, which is determined automatically for you when you don't set the `-n / --number` parameter.

The `timeit.timeit()` function, on the other hand, **doesn't repeat**. It runs the statement *number* of times, and gives you the *total time*. From the [`timeit.timeit()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit):

> Create a `Timer` instance with the given statement, *setup* code and *timer* function and run its `timeit()` method with number executions.

and from [`timeit.Timer.timeit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit):

> Time *number* executions of the main statement. This executes the setup statement once, and then **returns the time it takes to execute the main statement a number of times**, measured in seconds as a float.

If you want to get a *best out of* result, use the [`timeit.repeat()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.repeat):

> ```
>  timeit.repeat(stmt='pass', setup='pass', timer=<default timer>, repeat=3, number=1000000)
> ```
>
> Create a `Timer` instance with the given statement, *setup* code and *timer* function and run its `repeat() method` with the given *repeat* count and *number* executions.

Using `timeit.repeat()` will not auto-range the *number* for you however. For that you'd have to create your own `Timer()` instance.

The documentation links to the [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/timeit.py), so you can see how this is done in the `main()` function; simplifying this down to the code that is executed when you use the default options:

```
t = Timer(stmt, setup, timer)
repeat = 3
for i in range(1, 10):
    number = 10**i
    x = t.timeit(number)
    if x >= 0.2:
        break
r = t.repeat(repeat, number)
best = min(r)
print "%d loops," % number,
usec = best * 1e6 / number
if usec < 1000:
    print "best of %d: %.*g usec per loop" % (repeat, 3, usec)
else:
    msec = usec / 1000
    if msec < 1000:
        print "best of %d: %.*g msec per loop" % (repeat, 3, msec)
    else:
        sec = msec / 1000
        print "best of %d: %.*g sec per loop" % (repeat, 3, sec)
```

In Python 3, the above has been much improved with the new [`Timer.autorange()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.autorange) and a better handling of scales.

Demo using your statement and setup:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> t = timeit.Timer('char in text', setup='text = "sample string"; char = "g"')
>>> repeat = 3
>>> for i in range(1, 10):
...     number = 10**i
...     x = t.timeit(number)
...     if x >= 0.2:
...         break
...
>>> r = t.repeat(repeat, number)
>>> best = min(r)
>>> print "%d loops," % number,
10000000 loops,
>>> usec = best * 1e6 / number
>>> if usec < 1000:
...     print "best of %d: %.*g usec per loop" % (repeat, 3, usec)
... else:
...     msec = usec / 1000
...     if msec < 1000:
...         print "best of %d: %.*g msec per loop" % (repeat, 3, msec)
...     else:
...         sec = msec / 1000
...         print "best of %d: %.*g sec per loop" % (repeat, 3, sec)
...
best of 3: 0.0305 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit): It runs the main statement `number` times (default is `1000000`),
and returns the sum of time it took to execute all *number* times.

you can add `number=10**8` to your call and see how the result changes:

```py
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('char in text', setup='text = "sample string"; char = "g"')
0.03136014938354492
>>> timeit.timeit('char in text', setup='text = "sample string"; char = "g"', number=10**7)
0.22713899612426758
>>> timeit.timeit('char in text', setup='text = "sample string"; char = "g"', number=10**8)
2.130625009536743
>>>
```